# How to make smoke a different color?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, smoke-simulation

I have a smoke simulation with particles in blender. It's supposed to be a firework. There are particles emitted off a sphere, and the a smoke simulation. On the domain, the material color is blue like I want. In the render the blue will not appear though. The image has my node setup for the domain. Please help[image: ![node setup]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tjyY.png)

Comment: see if this helps you: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fblcl.png

Comment: @cegaton I did that node setup and all it did was add a little blue spot at the top of the smoke, it didn't cover it all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Volume Scatter node to be able to colour tint the smoke.

[image]